# Number output sometime have .0

Tags: python, while-loop, int, output

Code:

```
n = 18
total = 0
while n <=35:
 total += (n/2)
 print(total)
 n += 2
```

Output:`

```
9.0
19.0
30.0
42.0
55.0
69.0
84.0
100.0
117.0`
```

Second code:

```
n = 40
total = 2
while n >=25:
 total += n
 print(total)
 n -= 3 `
```

Output:

```
42
79
113
144
172
197
```

Question: Why is the first output have .0 behind the integer while second output does not have although 2 codes look similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, dividing two integers with the `/` operator produces `float` values, for example

```
>>> 1/2
0.5
```

... but also

```
>>> 1/1
1.0
```

(In Python 2, you would get `0` and `1`!)

In the first iteration, you are adding an `int` and `float` with `total += (n/2)` and two `float`s in subsequent iterations. Both of these additions produce `float` values.

The trailing `.0` only looks weird because you exclusively compute values that could be expressed as integers.

Having `int_a/int_b` become a `float` (in Python 3), even when the result could be written as an integer, is just consistent.

It would be weird if dividing some integers would produce `float` values and divinding some other integers would produce `int` values.

In your second code snippet, you only add and substract integers from each other, which produces `int` values, so you don't see a trailing `.0`.

Finally, if you want to enforce integer division, use the `//` operator.

```
>>> 1//2
0
>>> 1//1
1
```

`//` in Python 3 behaves like `/` did in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

The division operator `/` always results in a floating number in Python 3. You should use the integer division operator `//` instead if you are sure that `n` is always even, or if you don't need the remainder:

```
total += n // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

The operator '/' in Python3 returns you a float, to obtain integer as a result use integer division '//'.